# Getting attachment size from smtp server

Tags: c#, smtp, size, email-attachments

I have problem with getting attachment size from smtp server.

For example user wants to send mail from `smtp.gmail.com`, I need to know how big attachment can I attach.

So, I want to send `EHLO` command to smtp server, but I have problem with it.

```
private long GetSizeAttachament()
{
    long Size = 0; 
    TcpClient smtpTest = new TcpClient();

    try
    {
        smtpTest.Connect(conf.SmtpServer, 25);
        if (smtpTest.Connected)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = smtpTest.GetStream();
            StreamReader clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(ns);
            StreamWriter clientStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(ns);
            clientStreamReader.ReadLine();

            clientStreamWriter.WriteLine("EHLO somehost");
            while (true)
            {
                string line = clientStreamReader.ReadLine();
                if(line.StartsWith("250"))
                {
                    if (Regex.Match(line, "250-SIZE (.*?)$").Groups.Count > 1)
                    {
                        Size = long.Parse(Regex.Match(line, "250-SIZE (.*?)$").Groups[1].Value);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    smtpTest.Close();
    return Size;
}
```

`conf.SmtpServer` is smtp server name - for exmaple `smtp.gmail.com`.

This code is freezing at

```
string line = clientStreamReader.ReadLine();
```

Any ideas why?